# Call a C# web API service in a console application

Tags: c#, api, dependency-injection, console-application, service-provider

In one solution I have a .net 5 ASP.NET Core Web API, which contains an interface `IEmailSender` and the respective `EmailSender` implementation, and a console app project.
In the console app I have created a derived scheduled service, where in a `catch` block I want to use an `EmailSender` to send an email with details of an error thrown in the system.

```
public StockOpeningValuesUpdateScheduledService(IScheduleConfig<StockOpeningValuesUpdateScheduledService> config, IHttpClientFactory factory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            : base(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo, serviceProvider)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public override async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = _factory.CreateClient("trading");

                await client.PostAsync("company-buyable-shares/update-opening-values", null, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

                var emailSender = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailSender>();

                await emailSender.SendAbnormalEventEmailAsync(ex);
            }
        }
```

I call the scheduled service in `Program.cs` of the console app, and try to register the `EmailSender` as a scoped service.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHttpClient("trading", client =>
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44395"));

                services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>()
                .AddScheduledService<StockOpeningValuesUpdateScheduledService>(service =>
                {
                    service.CronExpression = "*/2 * * * *";
                    service.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
                });            
            });
```

When I simulate an error in the console app (in order to receive an email about it)
I get an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'StockTradingSimulator.BusinessLayer.Services.IEmailService' while attempting to activate 'StockTradingSimulator.BusinessLayer.Helpers.EmailSender'.
```

In the web API I have a setup as in my `catch` block above for another derived scheduled service which calls a scoped service method. This functionality is working, maybe because the scheduled service, and the scoped service and its interface are in the same project.

Does somebody have an idea how I can register and call successfully the `EmailSender` in my console app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **EmailSender** has unresolved dependencies. The dependency that is not resolved is **IEmailService**

The code and description you posted has no reference about the interface which is causing the error. Where is the implementation for **IEmailService**?

When you build the IServiceProvider, you need to have something that adds IEmailService to the DI container. Something like:

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailService, MyEmailService>();
```

Comment: I think this is only the first error, and not in the posted code. There are many parameters in the descrined service that are also not injected in the posted code.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I hadn't paid attention the error mentioned `IEmailService`, not `IEmailSender`. To `Program.cs` I have added all dependencies of `EmailSender`, one of which is `IEmailService`. They all live in the web API project. I am currently trying to read my API project `appsettings.json` file in the console app as the `EmailService` depends on it. I'll post an update.

Answer (score 0):

To `Program.cs` of the console app I added all dependencies of `EmailSender` and a way to access the `AppSettings` section of `appsettings.json` file of my web API, which section contains the SMTP details `EmailService` uses through dependency injection of `IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings`.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                    .Build();

                services.AddHttpClient("trading", client =>
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44395"));

                services.AddSingleton(configuration)
                .Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"))
                .AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>()
                .AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>()
                .AddDbContext<TradingDbContext>()
                .AddAutoMapper(typeof(BusinessLayerServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly)
                .AddScheduledService<StockOpeningValuesUpdateScheduledService>(service =>
                {
                    service.CronExpression = "*/1 * * * *";
                    service.TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
                });           
            });
```

**UPDATE:**
The correct way to access `appsettings.json` from the console app is decsribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960819/reference-web-api-appsettings-json-file-in-console-app-project-in-the-same-solut?noredirect=1#comment120121002_67960819). The above solution doesn't work when the console app is run with `dotnet run`.