# Reference Web API appsettings.json file in console app project in the same solution - issue with dotnet run

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application, projects-and-solutions, appsettings

I have a .net 5 ASP.NET Core Web API and a console app in one Visual Studio solution. I have an `appsettings.json` file in my API's host project, which file I want to reference in my console app. The file has `Copy if newer` for `Copy to Output Directory`.
The solution structure is as follows (non-relevant projects omitted):

- Solution

  - ApiHostProject

    - appsettings.json
  - ConsoleAppProject

This is my console app's `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static Task Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) => services.AddStockUpdater());
    }
```

Extension method `AddStockUpdater`, where I add the console app's dependencies:

```
internal static IServiceCollection AddStockUpdater(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var netFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var debugFolder = Directory.GetParent(netFolder).FullName;
            var binFolder = Directory.GetParent(debugFolder).FullName;
            var consoleAppFolder = Directory.GetParent(binFolder).FullName;
            var solutionFolder = Directory.GetParent(consoleAppFolder).FullName;
            var pathToFile = Path.Combine(solutionFolder, "StockTradingSimulator.ApiHost", "appsettings.json"); 

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile(pathToFile, false)
                    .Build();

            //URL of the Web API
            services.AddHttpClient("trading", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4000"));

            return services
                .AddSingleton(configuration)
                .Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"))
            // other dependencies omitted
}
```

This works if I set up the API host and the console app as startup projects and run them through Visual Studio (either via the Start button, or `Ctrl` + 5).
The `pathToFile` is `"C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\SolutionFolder\\StockTradingSimulator.ApiHost\\appsettings.json"`
However, if I run the console app project with `dotnet run` (from the directory containing the console app project file, or from another directory giving the path to the project file as `--project` parameter to `dotnet run`), I get an error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'StockTradingSimulator.ApiHost\appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Users\StockTradingSimulator.ApiHost\appsettings.json'.
```

Could you help me get the console app to find the API host's `appsettings.json` no matter whether the console app is run through Visual Studio or a `dotnet run` command?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286704/how-can-i-share-config-file-like-appsettings-json-across-multiple-asp-net-core-p/38288754) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170073/dotnet-core-3-1-how-to-use-addjsonfile-with-absolute-path-to-file) SO posts but they didn't help.

Comment: Have you every heard about Directory.Build.props? [Good Example](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/5255). There you can specify any kind of project properties for a set of projects in your solution.

Comment: @Martin thank you, very handy. Could you have a look at my last question about the connection string (as an answer to this post)?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to the console app project file:

```
<!-- Try and nest the appsettings when it's not a web sdk project. -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(IsSdkProject)' == 'true' AND '$(IsWebSdkProject)' == 'false'">
    <Content Include="..\StockTradingSimulator.ApiHost\appsettings.*.json">
      <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

When running the console app with `dotnet run`, the Web API `appsettings.json` file is now found.

I want to send an email from my console app, the email sender is in the web API project and has a dependency on the `dbContext`.

The Web API class derived from `DbContext` uses the following to get the connection string:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("StockTrading"));
```

`appsettings.json` contains the connection string to my SQL Server database.

`dotnet run` for the console app throws an error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')`

**UPDATE:**

Below is how I access the database connection string.

I have this constructor in my derived `DbContext` class:

```
public TradingDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
```

I wanted to get the connection string in `OnConfiguring()` method in the derived `DbContext` and just use `AddDbContext<TradingDbContext>()` here but this didn't work when running with `dotnet run`:

```
internal static IServiceCollection AddStockUpdater(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                    .Build();

            services.AddHttpClient("trading", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4000"));

            services
                .AddSingleton(configuration)
                .Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"))
                .AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>()
                .AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>()
                .AddDbContext<TradingDbContext>(options => options
                    .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("StockTrading")))
                .AddAutoMapper(typeof(BusinessLayerServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly)
                // other dependencies

            return services;
        }
```